# Magento Product URL

Tags: php, magento

There has been some discussions on how to have just 1 product url.

The problem:

Let’s say you have product a and you place that in Cat 1, subcat 1.

what you end up with is actually 4 seperate urls to that product:

```
http://www.url.com/producta.html <-- seen in autogenerated product site map 
http://www.url.com/category/subcategory/producta.html 
http://www.url.com/category/producta.html
```

My question goes like this:

if i enter this url to the browser:

```
http://www.url.com/producta.html
```

or

```
http://www.url.com/category/producta.html
```

this url will redirect to only one url:

http://www.url.com/category/subcategory/producta.html

Comment: you can use url rewrite management option in backend

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess it deals with dedirects 
Not sure what magneta is, but it could also be sending headers from

```
 http://www.url.com/producta.html
```

To redirect what it thinks are typos.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the URL to either include or exclude the category path. By default, the category path is included in all category and product pages.

1. From the Admin menu, select System > Configuration.
2. In the Configuration panel on the left, select Catalog. Click to expand the Search Engine Optimizations section. Then, do the following

   - To remove the suffix from product URLs, clear the default “.html”
     setting from the Product URL Suffix field.
   - To remove the suffix from
     category URLs, clear the default “.html” setting from the Category
     URL Suffix field.

Category path in url is better for seo purposes.

Comment: yes i saw that in admin but it does not solve my problem.


What i want is when i directly accwess this url to the browser:
http://www.url.com/producta.html

the page will be redirected to this url
http://www.url.com/category/subcategory/producta.html

Comment: set **Use Categories Path for Product URLs** to **NO** and clear your cache, I am sure this will exclude category name in product path.

Comment: For more details, please read http://blog.mattstephens.co.uk/post/24535726205/magento-canonical-category-url-paths-for-products

Comment: Murtaza is right,it is better to use exclude category path from product url.It good for heath of Seo point of view...Also

Comment: hi @murtzagondal based on this blog

http://blog.mattstephens.co.uk/post/24535726205/magento-canonical-category-url-paths-for-products

my question is, if i directly access this url to the browser:

http://www.url.com/honda_accord-black.html

i want that url will be redirected to

http://www.url.com/cars/honda/estates/honda_accord-black.html

and this url will appear on the browser.

Thanks

Comment: Yes if you remove the `->where('category_id=? OR category_id is NULL', $this->_urlRewriteCategory) // HERE ASSIGNED` and categories are set to Is Anchor yes. But keep in mind it will always show honda/estates/honda_accord-black.html  because estates id is less than hatchbacks

Comment: yes it is working in the product page but if i directly access this url (http://www.url.com/honda_accord-black.html) to the browser, no redirection occurs all i want is when i directly access this url (http://www.url.com/honda_accord-black.html) to the browser, it will redirect to (http://www.url.com/cars/honda/estates/honda_accord-black.html).